# When should avoid usage of Future in scala

Tags: scala, future

**Orignial Question**

1. Is there any situation we should avoid returning a `Future` from a class method? What is the cost of Futurizing a method?
2. What if other methods are returning `Future`, should we still futurize methods if the methods only perform trivial computations to keep the interface consistency?

I would like to know what is the overhead of Futurizing a method (If there's any)?

**Edit-1**

What is the cost/overhead of wrapping a method into `Future` in Scala (if any), in the context of Java Runtime?

I guess it will at least generate more Garbage for GC, but I am not sure.

Comment: *Any* situation? Sure. `def foo(x: Int): Int = x + 1` - There'd be no point in introducing `Future` to that.

Comment: You only need to use `Future` for asynchronous and non-blocking programming; for when you want to avoid threads having to wait for, for example, an I/O operation to finish. It makes no sense to use a `Future` for trivial operations that can be executed without blocking a thread. Don't do this just for the sake of interface consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to 'futurise' anything unless that method has asynchronous work to do, i.e. has to wait itself for futures. If the method takes too much time, the caller can always wrap the call into a `Future`. I would therefore conclude, don't use `Future` in your API until you really need it.

Answer (score 5):

There barely exists situation when you may need the `Future` result but should avoid it because of overhead.

Whole future concept is described [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

If in short - there is an [`ExecutionContext`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) and it is responsible for all overhead. It receives small closures and is running them as it likes to. The more of such closures exists, the more it should handle.

Every action creates new [`Promise`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise) which is shown as `Future` to you. *Every* means each `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and so on. Each *just do* operation like `forEach` or `onComplete` does not create new `Promise` but register new closure in the `ExecutionContext`.

All of this is not specifically heavy, but if **every** your method will be returning a `Future` it could be a problem.

So just follow reasonable minimalism, but if you need some streamed computation it's usually OK to make every step asynchronous.